# Can't set constraints programmatically after inflating the view

Tags: java, android

I am inflating a layout and I'm trying to set the constraints of the view objects after inflation. Here is the code:

```
LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
ConstraintLayout runSessionLayout = findViewById(R.id.runSessionLayout);

View buttonsLayout = linflater.inflate(R.layout.session_buttons_layout, runSessionLayout, false);
currentTime = buttonsLayout.findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
btnQuickLog = buttonsLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnSessionQuickLog);
btnNormalLog = buttonsLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnSessionNormalLog);
btnLiveLog = buttonsLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnSessionLiveLog);

runSessionLayout.addView(buttonsLayout);
set.clone(runSessionLayout);
set.connect(btnQuickLog.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, runSessionLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
set.applyTo(runSessionLayout);
```

The objects are inflated properly but the constraints are not added for some reason.

I tried this exact same code to set the constraint of a button that is in the "runSessionLayout" and for that the constraints were set. It looks like this doesn't work for objects of the inflated "buttonsLayout" and I can't understand why..

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem: I solved it by initiating the inflated view's constraint layout and cloning that with the constraint set.

Code changes:

```
cnsButtonsLayout = buttonsLayout.findViewById(R.id.sessionsButtonLayout);
set.clone(cnsButtonsLayout);
```